# Using Javascript Arrays in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

How do I use an element from an array in javascript in html which is declared outside the function?
I'm trying to use the elements of the array to create a graph but the graph doesnt show up in the webpage, I do not know why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>  
<title>xyz</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var x1=[],y1=[];

function define(){
x1={"1780330","1716120","1832015","1822602","1878293","1989673","2093379","2121345","2224831","2325575","2387188","2647722"};
y1={"42053.0","51667.5","47647.5","51539.5","49135.3","52750.1","48508.1","42877.4","53483.1","49935.8","45813.1","53521.8"};}

 window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
     zoomEnabled: true,
     title:{
      text: e11 "vs" e22      
    },
    animationEnabled: true,
    axisX:{

      title: xaxis,
      valueFormatString:  "#", 
      minimum: 1700000,
      maximum: 2700000
    },
    axisY:{
      title: yaxis,
      valueFormatString:  "#",
 minimum: 40000,
      maximum: 55000 
      
      

    },
    legend: {
      verticalAlign: "bottom",
      horizontalAlign: "left"

    },
    data: [
    {        
     type: "scatter",     
     color: "#778899",
     legendText: "Each circle represents one year",
     showInLegend: "true",
     markerType: "circle", 
     
     toolTipContent: "<span style='\"'color: CornflowerBlue;'\"'><strong></strong></span> {x}<br/> <span style='\"'color: ForestGreen;'\"'><strong></strong></span> {y}",

     dataPoints: [

     { x: x1[0], y: y1[0] },
     { x: x1[1], y: y1[1] },
     { x: x1[2], y: y1[2] },
     { x: x1[3], y: y1[3] },
     { x: x1[4], y: y1[4] },

     { x: x1[5], y: y1[5] },
     { x: x1[6], y: y1[6] },
     { x: x1[7], y: y1[7] },
     { x: x1[8], y: y1[8] },
     { x: x1[9], y: y1[9] },
     { x: x1[10], y: y1[10] },
     { x: x1[11], y: y1[11] },
   
     ]
   }
   ]
 });

chart.render();
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Rishika\Downloads\canvasjs-1.7.0\canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You can't load resources from local disk.  You need a web server and a relative path.

Comment: `text: e11 "vs" e22` does this work ? Doesn't look like valid JavaScript syntax

Comment: is `canvasjs.min.js` loading in the browser. Any error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>  
<title>xyz</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var x1=[], 
      y1=[],
      e11 = "Something",
      e22 = "something else";

  function define(){
    x1= [1780330, 1716120, 1832015, 1822602, 1878293, 1989673, 2093379, 2121345, 2224831, 2325575, 2387188, 2647722];
    y1=[42053.0, 51667.5, 47647.5, 51539.5, 49135.3, 52750.1, 48508.1, 42877.4, 53483.1, 49935.8, 45813.1, 53521.8];
  }

  window.onload = function () {
    define();
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
      {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        title:{
          text: e11 + " vs " + e22      
        },
        animationEnabled: true,
        axisX:{
          title: "xaxis",
          valueFormatString:  "#", 
          minimum: 1700000,
          maximum: 2700000
        },
        axisY:{
          title: "yaxis",
          valueFormatString:  "#",
          minimum: 40000,
          maximum: 55000 
        },
        legend: {
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          horizontalAlign: "left"
        },
        data: [
          {        
            type: "scatter",     
            color: "#778899",
            legendText: "Each circle represents one year",
            showInLegend: "true",
            markerType: "circle", 
            toolTipContent: '<span style="color: CornflowerBlue;"><strong></strong></span> {x}<br/> <span style="color: ForestGreen;"><strong></strong></span> {y}',
            dataPoints: x1.map(function(d, i) { return {x: d, y: y1[i]};})
          }
        ]
      }
   );
   chart.render();
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

</body>
```

There was a ton of stuff that needed fixing.  `e11` and `e22` weren't defined.  You never called `define` to set `x1` and `y1`.  `x1` and `y1` were filled with strings instead of numbers.  Your `tooltipcontent` option had extra apostrophes.  Your axis titles weren't strings.  All of these things raise errors and prevent the Chart function from finishing.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be an issue with how you define your x1, y1 arrays.  Arrays use `[]`, not the `{}` that Objects use.

Try `x1=[...]`